# How can one access first parameter of a function using stack frame?

Tags: c, gcc, stack

There's a series of problems in [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com) about creating a function in a single line with some constraints. I've already solved the easy, medium and hard ones, but for the [impossible](http://www.spoj.com/problems/THINKLOL/) one I keep getting Wrong Answer.

To sum it up, the problem requests to fill in the code of the return statement such that if x is 1, the return value should be 2. For other x values, it should return 3. The constraint is that the letter 'x' can't be used, and no more code can be added; one can only code that return statement. Clearly, to solve this, one must create a hack.

So I've used gcc's built in way to get the stack frame, and then decreased the pointer to get a pointer to the first parameter. Other than that, the statement is just a normal comparison.

On my machine it works fine, but for the cluster (Intel Pentinum G860) used by the online judge, it doesn't work, probably due to a different calling convention. I'm not sure I understood the processor's [ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (I'm not sure if the stack frame pointer is saved on the stack or only on a register), or even if I'm reading the correct ABI.

The question is: what would be the correct way to get the first parameter of a function using the stack?

My code is (it must be formatted this way, otherwise it's not accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(int x){

 return (*(((int*)__builtin_frame_address(0))-1) == 1) ? 2 : 3;

}

int main(i){
    for(i=1;i%1000001;i++)
        printf("%d %d\n",i,count(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the sake of readibility you should format your code properly here. SPOJ requirements in this matter, well, don't matter.

Comment: Although the illegible part of the code doesn't matter, as the code is not really necessary to the answer (it just prints the result of the function for all values from 1 to 1000001), I'll do that.

Comment: @ryyker The point of the question according to the OP is to compare against the value of `x` without the character `x` appearing in the code.

Comment: @ryyker, Degustaf is correct, and I don't see why that link is relevant to this question.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried this myself, and even though I get the correct output on both 32-bit and 64-bit Linux and OS X using gcc and clang, SPOJ gives wrong answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: what would be the correct way to get the first
>   parameter of a function using the stack?

There is no way in portable manner. You must assume specific compiler, its settings and ABI, along with calling conventions.

The `gcc` compiler is *likely* to "lay down" an `int` local variable with `-0x4` offset (assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`). You might observe with most basic definition of `count`:

```
4   {
   0x00000000004004c4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004c5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004c8 <+4>: mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)

5       return x == 1 ? 2 : 3;
   0x00000000004004cb <+7>: cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004cf <+11>:    jne    0x4004d8 <count+20>
   0x00000000004004d1 <+13>:    mov    $0x2,%eax
   0x00000000004004d6 <+18>:    jmp    0x4004dd <count+25>
   0x00000000004004d8 <+20>:    mov    $0x3,%eax

6   }
   0x00000000004004dd <+25>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000004004de <+26>:    retq
```

You may also see that `%edi` register holds first parameter. This is the case for [AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf) (`%edi` is also not preserved between calls).

Now, with that knowledge, you might write something like:

```
int count(int x)
{
    return *((int*)(__builtin_frame_address(0) - sizeof(int))) == 1 ? 2 : 3;
}
```

which can be obfuscated as:

```
return *((int*)(__builtin_frame_address(0)-sizeof(int)))==1?2:3;
```

However, trick is that such [*optimizing compiler*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) may enthusiastically assume that since `x` is not referenced in `count`, it could simply skip moving into stack. For example it produces following assembly with `-O` flag:

```
4   {
   0x00000000004004c4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004c5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp

5       return *((int*)(__builtin_frame_address(0)-sizeof(int)))==1?2:3;
   0x00000000004004c8 <+4>: cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004004cc <+8>: setne  %al
   0x00000000004004cf <+11>:    movzbl %al,%eax
   0x00000000004004d2 <+14>:    add    $0x2,%eax

6   }
   0x00000000004004d5 <+17>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000004004d6 <+18>:    retq
```

As you can see `mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)` instruction is now missing, thus the only way<sup>1</sup> would be to access value of `x` from `%edi` register:

```
int count(int x)
{
    return ({register int edi asm("edi");edi==1?2:3;});
}
```

but this method lacks of ability to "obfuscate", as whitespaces are needed for variable declaration, that holds value of `%edi`.

<sup>1) Not necessarily. Even if compiler decides to skip `mov` operation from register to stack, there is still a possibility to "force" it to do so, by `asm("mov %edi,-0x4(%rbp)");` inline assembly. Beware though, compiler may have its revenge, sooner or later.</sup>

Comment: Can you just use the value returned from the inline assembly directly, and not store it in a variable?  `asm("edi") == 1 ? 2 : 3;`?  My whitespace is for readability, and can be removed for the problem.

Comment: @Degustaf: See [6.43.5.2 Specifying Registers for Local Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html), but I don't think, that is possible. You might also try with [basic asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm) and [extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski, thank you for your answer. It seems like it's the case of a register being used instead of the stack. I'll look more into your answer when I get back from work.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski, ok, that's exactly what I thought; I see no other way to answer this question. I'll mark your answer as accepted, but if you have any other thoughts on the subject, feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

C standard does NOT require a stack in any implementation, so really your problem doesn't make any sense.

in the context of gcc, the behavior is different in x86 and x86-64(and any others).

in x86, parameters reside in stack, but in x86-64, the first 6 parameters(including the implicit ones) reside in registers. so basically you can't do the hacking as you say.

if you want to hack the code, you need to specify the platform you want to run on, otherwise, there is no point to answer your question.

Comment: As said (and misspelt) in question, the platform used for compiling is an Intel Pentium G860.